# Is there a closed form expression for $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a-cos\theta}d\theta$?

Tags: integration

Is there a closed form results for this integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a-cos\theta}d\theta
$$
where a > 1.

Comment: The expression is a rational function on $\cos$ and $\sin$, yes there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

you can use the substitution:

$$
u=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)
$$

that gives:
$$
\cos x= \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2} \qquad dx=\frac{2 du}{1+u^2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

With residue calculus we can evaluate it without any difficulty.

Setting $z = e^{i\theta}$ we have

$$\cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}(z + z^{-1})$$

So

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-i}{z\left(a - \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)}\ \text{d}z$$

We denote

$$f(z) = \frac{-i}{z\left(a - \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)\right)} = \frac{i}{z^2 - za + 1}$$

Since $a > 1$ you will get real or complex roots respectively for $a \geq 2$ and $1 < a < 2$.

If you know how to compute residues, after putting in the unit circle you will have to compute

$$2\pi i \sum_{\alpha} \text{res}(f(z), z_{\alpha})$$

**In the end**

$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{a - \cos\theta}\ \text{d}\theta = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}}\pi}{1+a}$$

Which **since $a > 1$** becomes

$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{a - \cos\theta}\ \text{d}\theta = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Put the integral in standard form:
$$\int\frac1{a-\cos\theta}d\theta=\frac1a\int\frac1{1-\frac1a\cos\theta}d\theta=\frac1a\int\frac1{1+e\cos\nu}d\nu$$
where $0<e=\frac1a<1$ is the eccentricity and $\nu=\theta-\pi$ is the true anomaly. Convert to eccentric anomaly:
$$\sin E=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin\nu}{1+e\cos\nu},\,\cos E=\frac{\cos\nu+e}{1+e\cos\nu},\,dE=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{1+e\cos\nu}d\nu$$
Then
$$\int\frac1{a-\cos\theta}d\theta=\frac1{a\sqrt{1-e^2}}\int dE=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-1}}E+C$$
When $\theta=0,\,\nu=-\pi,\,\sin E=0,\,\cos E=-1,\,E=-\pi$.
When $\theta=\pi,\,\nu=0,\,\sin E=0,\,\cos E=1,\,E=0$.
So $$\int_0^{\pi}\frac1{a-\cos\theta}d\theta=\frac1{a\sqrt{1-e^2}}\int_{-\pi}^0 dE=\left.\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-1}}E\,\right|_{-\pi}^0=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$
The eccentric anomaly goes back at least to Kepler, who used it to express his law of areas (which is the geometric equivalent of conservation of angular momentum).

Answer (score 1):

do you know complex analysis, the Cauchy integral formula, the residue theorem ? if not, write $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{a - \cos \theta} d\theta = \frac12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a - \cos \theta} d\theta =  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2a - e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}} d\theta = - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{i \theta}}{e^{2i \theta} - 2a e^{i \theta}  + 1} d\theta $$ $$= -  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{i \theta}}{(e^{i \theta}-\rho_1)(e^{i \theta}-\rho_2)} d\theta = \alpha \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{i \theta}}{e^{i \theta}-\rho_1} d\theta + \beta\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{i \theta}}{e^{i \theta}-\rho_2} d\theta$$

where $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are obtained by factorization of the polynomial $z^2 - 2az + 1$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are obtained by identification (or partial fraction decomposition).

and the last integrals can be easily evaluated, obtaining :

$$ = \alpha 2 i \pi \ 1_{|\rho_1| < 1} + \beta 2 i \pi \  1_{|\rho_2| < 1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Two methods have already been given on paths to obtain the integral's value. It is fairly evident that the general integral can take on the form
$$\int \frac{d\theta}{a - \cos\theta} = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \, \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{(a+1) \, \tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \right).$$
For the limits given it is seen that $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \infty$ and $\tan\left(\frac{0}{2}\right) = 0$. Using $\tanh^{-1}(\infty) = - \frac{\pi i}{2}$ and $\tanh^{-1}(0) = 0$ then the integral in question becomes
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{a - \cos\theta} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2 - 1}}.$$